# batchscript: Read file line by line and extract paths

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file

I want to read a file content line by line and then in each line I want to retrieve only the paths.

**sample.txt:**

```
\.\docusp\ui\test\java\services\gway->\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\gway  pserver\2 (5660\1) (backed) (elink)
\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\services\run->\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\rip  pserver\1 (376\1) (backed) (elink)
```

**Output:**

```
path: \.\docusp\ui\test\java\services\gway
target: \.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\gway
path: \.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\services\run
target:\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\rip
```

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\sample.txt) DO ( 
    ECHO Line is: %%a
    set line=%%a

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("%line%") do (
        echo %%a
        echo %%b
        set path=%%a
        set target=%%b
        REM target contains the substring after ->. Want to remove  "pserver\2 (5660\1) (backed) (elink)" string
    )
)
```

In each line target contains,

```
\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\rip  pserver\1 (376\1) (backed) (elink)
```

Need to remove `pserver\1 (376\1) (backed) (elink)` and target should only contain `\.\docusp\ui\test\java\pserv\com\controller\services\rip`.

**Note:** target path may contain space in between. based on space and get substring will not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to misinterpret the `delims` option of `for /F`; it specifies a list of characters that act as delimiters, but not strings...

Comment: …although in this case, as they're the only visible instances of those characters, it should correctly identify `path`, **which should not be named as such**, _as it will overwrite your existing system variable_, and `target` should contain the rest of the line, (for further refinement), _but in order to do so, **you'd need to enable and use delayed expansion** too_!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not clear about the *details* of your problem that are important, so I must did a guess about these two points:

- The separation between the target and the part you want to remove is **TWO SPACES** as shown in the provided sample.txt file.
- When you said *"target path may contain space in between"* I assume that the target path may contain **ONE SPACE** in between, not two adjacent spaces...

The working solution below is based on such assumptions.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (sample.txt) DO ( 
    ECHO Line is: %%a
    set line=%%a

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("!line:  =-!") do (
        echo path: %%a
        echo target: %%b
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Basically am not familiar with Batch script.      Instead of ("!line:  =-!"), used ("!line:pserver=-!"). because in my case pserver is constant in each line and it wont be there in path.

Comment: I think that in this case you get the target path with two spaces at end...